# selenium script in jmeter

Tags: selenium, jmeter

I had write a script using selenium in Jmeter. Imported all the packages.

```
var pkg=JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium) //import java selenium package
var support_ui=JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait) 
var ui=JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui) 
var wait=new support_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser,5000) 
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('https://www.google.com')
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

to simply open the page.

it doesn't show any results in Listener.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you added the relevant **Config** element, like:

   - [Firefox Driver Config](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FirefoxDriverConfig/)
   - [Chrome Driver Config](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ChromeDriverConfig/)
   - [Phantom JS Driver Config](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PhantomJSDriverConfig/)
   - or whatever browser you're trying to use?
2. If yes and you still experience problems - check **jmeter.log** file - it usually contains enough troubleshooting information. The most common errors are:

   - libraries conflict. Selenium requires newer HTTP libraries version than JMeter so:

     - open /lib folder of your JMeter installation
     - locate .jar files which names start with `http`
     - delete duplicate .jar files with lesser version
   - unsupported browser (mostly affects Firefox). If you're trying to run Selenium test on Firefox - make sure you use one of the supported versions. Latest JMeter Plugins WebDriver Set 1.3.1 comes with Selenium 2.47.0 and according to the [changelog](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/CHANGELOG) it should be:

     > Supports native events for Firefox version 31 (immediately previous ESR).
     >
     > Native event support has been discontinued for versions of Firefox later
     >   than 33. Synthetic events tested on Firefox versions 31 (immediately
     >   previous ESR), 38 (immediately previous release and current ESR), and 39
     >   (current release).

For extra information and tips on using WebDriver Sampler in JMeter check out [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) guide